# WPF Restrict ResourceDictionary to assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am using C# 4.7.2 and WPF 4.5

I want register resources that defined in a specific assembly to be registered explicitly in the defining assembly. The application is exensible and I'm looking for a way to avoid name duplicates and the erros thrown as a result to them.

Is it possible to restricht the scope for resources? Does anybody know a way, to use names for dictionaries?

I'v tried a derivation from ResourceDictionary. But this derivation isn't accepted as parameter to

*System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add*

Answer (score 0):

When you merge a resource you do so with a scope.
Application.current.resources is where stuff you merge in app.xaml goes.
Below that... you have control scope.
A project / dll which you reference loads into the application's scope ( simplifying ). So you would need each view or whatever in that dll to load an instance of your resource dictionary. Which could of course have significant overhead.

A simple work round would be to have a prefix on the x:Key of your resources which is unique to each assembly.

Comment: Thanks Andy. But I'm afraid the scope is ALWAYS the executing assembly. In my case, the resources are located in a satellite library, which is unkown to the executing Assembly. The scope of the satellite resources is the executing assembly - proven.

I am aware of qualified names, but I am trying different approaches, as well.